# Kubernetes cannot pull a locally built image

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am using kubernetes 1.26 and I have a kubernetes cluster with a single node which is both master and worker.
I have built a docker image locally and I can list the image with docker images command:

```
$ sudo docker images | grep nipun

nipun/a                                                                    1.0                 ed1059539edf   52 minutes ago   250MB
```

But when I use this image "nipun/a:1.0"  with imagePullPolicy "Never" or "IfNotPresent" in a deployment, then also Kubernetes tries to pull the image and fails. My deployment definition is below:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1    
kind: Deployment    
metadata:   
  name: nipun-deployment
  labels:
    app: nipun
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nipun
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nipun
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nipun
        image: nipun/a:1.0
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8112
```

What might be the problem here ? I was using the same approach with lower version of k8s (1.20 probably) and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

You have first to build your own [local docker registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/):

```yaml
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry registry:2
```

Then, you can push your image to the registry as follows:

```yaml
docker tag nipun/a:1.0 localhost:5000/nipun/a:1.0
docker push localhost:5000/nipun/a:1.0
```

Set the image name with the local registry in your deployment:

```yaml
localhost:5000/nipun/a:1.0
```